# JPA custom objects with aliases for native query

Tags: java, sql, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have an entity profiles for which i am trying to find the count of all the profile with a specific titile in a date range and group by each date.

The profile entity looks like this-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {
    @Column(
        name = "created_at",
        columnDefinition = "bigint",
        nullable = false
    )
    @CreatedDate
    private Long createdAt;

    @Column(name = "title", columnDefinition = "varchar(255)")
    private String title;
}
```

A DTO for the result-

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserCreatedByDate {    
    private String created;
    private Long counter;
}
```

I have created a JPA repository for it -

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile, Long> {
@Query(value = "select FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at/1000,'%m-%d-%Y') as created, count(*) as counter from " +
            "profile where title like :title% and created_at >= :from and created_at < :to " +
            "group by created",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserCreatedByDate> findCountAllCreatedBetweenGroupByDate(@Param("from") Long from, @Param("to") Long to, @Param("title") String title);
}
```

This gives me these exception-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet;
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Apart from the above I tried using this-

```
@Query(value = "select new com.example.project.domain.UserCreatedByDate(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at/1000,'%m-%d-%Y'), count(1)) from " +
            "profile where title like :title% and created_at >= :from and created_at < :to " +
            "group by created",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserCreatedByDate> findCountAllCreatedBetweenGroupByDateCustom(@Param("from") Long from, @Param("to") Long to, @Param("title") String title);
```

and turned UserCreatedByDate to an interface-

```
public interface UserCreatedByDate {
    String getCreated();
    Long getCounter();
}
```

This gives me error in mysql statement which i am not able to identify. The same query works fine when run on db.

The query should return results like this-

```
created        counter
01-20-2023  1
01-27-2023  4
01-30-2023  3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your case your are not executing the query with `Interface Projection` in a correct way:

The Interface Projection:

```
public interface UserCreatedByDate {

  String getCreated();

  String getCounter();

}
```

The query in Repository(in my case I tried to check it with Postgresql where function `FROM_UNIXTIME` is not present by the way it is not a problem):

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT to_char(date(to_timestamp(created_at/1000)), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as created, count(*) as counter from " +
      " profile_entity where title like :title and created_at >= :from and created_at < :to " +
      "group by profile_entity.created_at",
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<UserCreatedByDate> findCountAllCreatedBetweenGroupByDate(@Param("from") Long from,
      @Param("to") Long to, @Param("title") String title);
```

After it i got the next one result, that meet 100% your requirements:

[image]

P.S. The problem was in the repository query(you are using interface projection as DTO projection)